# Can a linearly homogeneous function be concave?

Tags: convex-analysis, homogeneous-equation

If a function $f(x)$ ($x$ being a vector) is linearly homogeneous in $x$ (i.e. $k^{\lambda}f(x)=f(kx)\:;\:\: \lambda=1$), then can it also be said to be concave in $x$?

In an answer to [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3503640/need-help-understanding-the-scaling-properties-of-the-legendre-transformation), the answerer mentions that a function with degree of homogeneity greater than 1 ($\lambda>1$) is the "convex case". May I conclude that a homogeneous function with $0<\lambda<1$ is the concave case, and that functions with $\lambda=1$ are therefore not concave in $x$?

The motivation for this question is a seminal economics paper which asserts that a certain function is linearly homogeneous in a certain variable, say $w$, and then subsequently "proves" that the same function is also concave in $w$. I'm trying to understand in what sense these two things can both be true.

EDIT: In response to John Hughes' comment, here are the other stated properties of the function in question. Let this function be denoted $C(y, w)$, $y$ being a scalar and $w$ being a vector.

Property 1: $C(y,w)$ is a nonnegative function.

Property 2: $C(y,w)$ is positively linearly homogeneous in $w$ for each fixed $y$.

Property 3: $C(y,w)$ is nondecreasing in $w$ for each fixed $y$.

Property 4: $C(y,w)$ is a concave function of $w$ for each fixed $y$.

My question in this post is essentially "Don't properties 2 and 4 contradict each other?"

Each of these Properties is accompanied by a proof. The paper goes on to prove three more Properties:

Property 5: $C(y,w)$ is a continuous function of $w$ for each fixed $y$.

Property 6: $C(y,w)$ is nondecreasing in $y$ for fixed $w$.

Property 7: For every $w >> 0$, $C(y,w)$ is continuous from below in $y$.

The full treatment can be found on pages 4-6 [here](https://econ2017.sites.olt.ubc.ca/files/2018/02/pdf_paper_erwin-diewert-18-02-DualityInProduction.pdf).

Comment: Does the function have any other known properties (differentiable? Continuous? ...)

Comment: @JohnHughes See edit.

Comment: Do you have the roles of $w$ and $y$ swapped? Seems as if $w$ is the scalar. Assuming so, none of the first four properties say anything that would imply property 6 (at least nothing that I can see).

Comment: AH...and now that I look at the paper, I see that there's an assumption that $C$ is derived from something known to be continuous from above. Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add something, since I stumbled on this question, and have had a hard time figuring out ben's answer.

Consider the function $f(x,y) = x^a y ^{1-a}$, where $0<a<1$, and $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^+$. It is clear that ***this is homogenous of degree 1***, since
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(\alpha x,\alpha y) &= (\alpha x)^a (\alpha y) ^{1-a}\\
&= \alpha^a \alpha^{1-a} x^a y^{1-a}\\
&= \alpha x^a y^{1-a}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Economists will recognize this as a CRS production function. Note that this function is NOT both convex and concave. ***It is concave only.***

First, take the Hessian:
$$
H = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 (a-1) a x^{a-2} y^{1-a} & (1-a) a x^{a-1} y^{-a} \\
 (1-a) a x^{a-1} y^{-a} & -(1-a) a x^a y^{-a-1} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Note that ben is correct to say that a continuous $f$ is weakly concave if and only if the Hessian is negative semidefinite (and the converse for convexity).

Moreover, a symmetric matrix is negative semidefinite if and only if all of its principal minors of an odd order are $\le 0$, and all of its principal minors of an even order are $\ge 0$. In this case, we need therefore only check the entry in the top left is $\le 0$, and the determinant of the entire matrix is $\ge 0$. A symmetric matrix is positive semidefinite if and only if all of its principal minors are $\ge 0$.

Recall that $x,y\ge 0$. One can calculate the determinant and find that it is $0$. However, since $0<a<1$, the top left entry is negative. Thus, this Hessian is negative semidefinite.

So, the function is ***only concave***.

Of course, ***there exist functions that are homogenous of degree $1$ and are only convex.***

Consider, for example, a cone:

$$f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$
Then, this is homogenous of degree 1:

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(\alpha x,\alpha y) &= \sqrt{\alpha^2(x^2 + y^2)}\\
&= \alpha\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}
\end{aligned}
$$

And yet of course a cone is convex, not concave.
$$
H = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-\frac{x^2}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{3/2}} & -\frac{x y}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{3/2}} \\
 -\frac{x y}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{3/2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-\frac{y^2}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{3/2}} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Which you can again confirm has determinant of $0$ and has a first principal minor that is $\ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$ is linearly homogeneous in a single variable $x$, then

$$f(ax)=af(x) \tag{1}$$

Can $f(x)$ be considered concave? Yes, but it can just as well be considered convex.

Proof:

The condition for convexity is

$$f(tx + (1-t)y) \leq tf(x) + (1-t)f(y) \tag{2}$$

$\forall t \in [0,1], \forall x,y \in X$ where $X$ is a convex set (following [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function)).

Conversely, the condition for concavity is

$$f(tx + (1-t)y) \geq tf(x) + (1-t)f(y) \tag{3}$$

Note that $y$ can be expressed $y=xk$, where $k$ is not something bizarre or ridiculous. Substituting this into $(2)$ gives

$$f(tx + (1-t)xk) \leq tf(x) + (1-t)f(xk)$$

On the left hand side, the $x$ can be factored out

$$f(x(t + (1-t)k))$$

Now, if $f(x)$ is linearly homogeneous in $x$, then, by $(1)$, the factor $t + (1-t)k$ can be factored out of the function, so that this becomes

$$(t + (1-t)k)f(x)$$

Meanwhile, on the right hand side, also by $(1)$, the $k$ can be factored out of the function, i.e.,

$$tf(x) + (1-t)kf(x)$$

and then the $f(x)$ can be factored out, resulting in

$$(t + (1 - t)k)f(x)$$

which is *equal* to the left hand side.

Therefore, the condition $(2)$ is met, but so is condition $(3)$, meaning $f(x)$ is both convex and concave.

For a function of multiple variables $f(\mathbf{x})$ where $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector, the condition for convexity is

$$\mathbf{x} \cdot H \cdot \mathbf{x} \geq 0 \tag{4}$$

where $H$ is the Hessian matrix of $f(x)$. Conversely,

$$\mathbf{x} \cdot H \cdot \mathbf{x} \leq 0 \tag{5}$$

is the condition for concavity

Meanwhile, it can be shown that functions homogeneous of degree $h$ do this:

$$H \cdot \mathbf{x} = (h - 1) \nabla f$$

By which it is easy to see that if $f(\mathbf{x})$ is linearly homogeneous, i.e. has $h=1$, then

$$H \cdot \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$$

and hence

$$\mathbf{x} \cdot H \cdot \mathbf{x} = 0$$

Therefore, multivariate linearly homogeneous functions satisfy both $(4)$ and $(5)$, and so are both concave and convex.

Comment: This answer is valid for functions that are differentiable on $X$, and also you didn't consider the fact that $C$ is *positively* linearly homogeneous in $w$, meaning that $a \geq 0$. There exists functions that are *positively* linearly homogeneous, concave and that are not convex. Take any norm $||.||$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, the function $x\longmapsto -||x||$ is such a function.

Comment: @Theleb I didn't explicitly say "positively" but that is what I had in mind. I don't see how the above conclusion is altered, either in the univariate or multivariate case, by restricting $a$ (or $k$) to positive values. If I am mistaken, please point out the specific step(s) where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Okay, first of all the $k$ that you mention in the unidimensional case such that $y = kx$, after inequality (3), is not necessarily positive ($x = 3$ and $y = -3$ for example), therefore $t+(1-t)k$ is not necessarily positive either, hence you cannot use $positive$ linear homogeneity of $f$. On the other hand, in order for the hessian matrix to exist you need differentiability of $f$ and this disrupts your argument in multi-dimension if $f$ isn't differentiable. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: where did you get that $H \cdot \mathbf{x}=(1-h) \nabla f$? Don't the examples I provide disprove it?

Answer (score 0):

Take any norm $||.||$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, the function $x\longmapsto -||x||$ is :

1. positively linearly homogeneous (definition of a norm)
2. concave (triangular inequality)
3. not convex (equality case in triangular inequality)